# Can we get more mods?

Tags: discussion, moderation

The mods we have do great work and this is in no way intended as criticism. But I think the frequency of new content on this site outweighs the frequency of moderation work due to there being too few moderators.

It could be a timezone issue, or it could be sheer bad luck when things fly under the radar for both (?) of the active mods.

E.g. [Diet/exercise plan for lean bulking](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/38224/diet-exercise-plan-for-lean-bulking)

Here, the user Yung has posted two answers in an attempt to reply to other answers. I flagged them as "hey, delete this" 5 days ago, but they're still up.

Of course, this can easily happen if moderators go on vacation, have busy days, or for a plethora of reasons. And I'm NOT criticizing anyone. But if I'm not mistaken, we only have 1 or 2 active moderators, and it's summertime. It's not a far stretch to assume that there will be moderation downtime.

So yeah, this is not a criticism of the quality of work, but rather the quantity of workers. We could use one or two more, I think.

Thoughts?

Comment: This last week I think 2/3 of our moderators (myself included) were out of cell range / not online, just to tuck that in there.

Comment: I know at another mod has been on vacation. I've been busy this summer season myself, and in full disclosure I had communicated with the Community Team at Stack Exchange about stepping down as a moderator and having someone replace me since it is becoming more increasingly difficult for me to devote time to this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually in review, and I think this week was an unfortunate congruence. I was out for a week competing at our World Championships, with (almost) no access to Stack Exchange, and Eric was also away at the same time.

I have also been working with another moderator and the CM team to get more assistance, and that is in progress it will just take a bit of time. The good news is that the possible candidate is in a very different time zone which would give us better coverage.

Comment: Yes, different timezone would be good I think :)